# Google calendar api auth for web app flask app

Tags: python, flask, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

When testing locally, i used the desktop version of client id for the api as it was simpler and it did everything i wanted perfectly.

I have now changed the client id to a web app version and I can't get it to work. I can generate the url for the consent to be given by the user and link their account but it wont redirect to it.

Here's what i used before when it was the desktop version:

```
def find_creds():
  creds = None
  if current_user.token_json:
    credentials_dict = json.loads(current_user.token_json)
    creds = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(credentials_dict["token"], refresh_token=credentials_dict["refresh_token"], token_uri=credentials_dict["token_uri"], client_id=credentials_dict["client_id"], client_secret=credentials_dict["client_secret"], scopes=credentials_dict["scopes"])
  if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
      creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
      flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
             'credentials.json', SCOPES)
      creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
      current_user.token_json = creds.to_json()
      db.session.commit()
  return creds
```

This is what i have set up now:

```
def find_creds():
    if not current_user.token_json:
        print("not creds")
        get_creds()
    else:
        credentials_dict = json.loads(current_user.token_json)
        creds = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
            credentials_dict["token"],
            refresh_token=credentials_dict["refresh_token"],
            token_uri=credentials_dict["token_uri"],
            client_id=credentials_dict["client_id"],
            client_secret=credentials_dict["client_secret"],
            scopes=credentials_dict["scopes"])
        return creds


def get_creds():
    print("got to get_creds")
    flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file("creds2.json", scopes=SCOPES)
    flow.redirect_uri = url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)
    authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
        access_type='offline', prompt='consent'
    )
    print("made to redirect url")
    print(authorization_url)
    return redirect(authorization_url)


@app.route('/oauth2callback')
def oauth2callback():
    print("made to auth callback")
    flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file("creds2.json", scopes=SCOPES)
    flow.redirect_uri = url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)
    authorization_response = request.url
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
    current_user.token_json = flow.credentials.to_authorized_user_info()
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

When i try to redirect to "authorization_url" it doesn't work. I used print statements to test it and i can print the url and click it but for some reason, it won't just redirect.

I currently have it hosted on render not locally anymore as the redirect_uri's have to be https.

I can't seem to find the right documentation for this as well, only for the desktop version which doesn't work.

Any help or the correct link for the documentation would be great, thanks.